# Which version of PHPUnit for zf-1 and zf-2 applications

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I am using zf-1.12 with phpunit 4.0 and dbunit package. I got some issues while running test cases. it was regarding to redeclaration of some dbunit classes

After doing some troubleshot i noticed that these classes are available within phpunit itself and some 'require_once' lines in zend_test component were re-including same dbunit extension classes. I commented the lines to resolve the issue but I also come to know that ZF1 only support phpunit 3.4 or lesser version. So now I have some questions.

1. Which version of phpunit i should use with zf-1.12 and what new feature I won't be able to use with older version of phpunit.
2. If I upgrade my code to ZF2 then what version of phpunit I would be able to use.
3. Please also let me know if there is better other way to unit test zf application than using phpunit.

Thanks

Comment: I would definitely upgrade to ZF2 if that is a possibility! Then you can use Composer to bring in PHPUnit as a dependency. i.e. "phpunit/phpunit" : "3.7.*",

Comment: thanks for reply...but this is not answer of my questions...

Comment: As of now, Zend Framework 1.12 supports at least phpunit 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which version of phpunit i should use with zf-1.12 and what new
>   feature I won't be able to use with older version of phpunit.

You said your research came up with phpunit 3.4 with zf 1.12. I don't think you will notice much difference, all the main asserts will be there.

> If I upgrade my code to ZF2 then what version of phpunit I would be
>   able to use.

If this is an option, do it! Not just for a newer version of phpunit, but for a newer version Zend. Also you will be able to use composer to manage your dependencies.

> Please also let me know if there is better other way to unit test zf
>   application than using phpunit.

Phpunit is the standard & recommended way. For mocking, you could use Mockery with phpunit.

However, as an alternative, you could use phpspec.